# Connection time in Budapest is 55 minutes enough?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, transit, short-connections, bud

I'm traveling from Dublin to Budapest with Aer Lingus, then catching a connecting flight to Doha with Qatar. I have 55 mins between flights, I have not been to Budapest but believe it's quite small. Will I have to clear customs again or is the check in Dublin enough till I get to my final destination?

Comment: Dublin and Budapest are both in the EU, so there certainly won't be any strange _customs_ requirements. The real questions is whether the two airlines will cooperate in checking your baggage through -- is your itinerary all on a single ticket?

Comment: Transit at Budapest, what they will come up with next! Is there even airside transit for outside-of-Schengen to outside-of-Schengen travellers? All twenty of them who do this on any given day :P ? Per http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/38599/4188 Aer Lingus will interline with Qatar if you are on a single ticket. If not? Heaven knows. It depends on the mood of the agent. Smile and ask politely.

Comment: There is definitely airside Transit in Budapest

Comment: I haven't lived in Budapest since Hungary is in Schengen and I have been pretty zombie from transatlantic flights before getting to Budapest and so I can't for my life remember whether there is a fork in flow before you get to immigration. I'd not be surprised if it existed for within Schengen but really, this actually exists for outside of Schengen to outside of Schengen? Wow. Well, one thing for sure: you can't find such information on their website.

Comment: Flights wihtin Schengen are treated as domestic flights would be in the rest of the world. Airside Transit means transferring between itnernational flights without entering the Country of the Airport. The Country, in this case, is not Hungary, but Schengen

Answer (score 1):

Is it on one ticket? Then you'll be perfectly fine. If not, I highly doubt it since you have both in- and outbound passport checks (to collect and re-check baggage), and the Queues could very well be long

Comment: Protip: if you pay the express security fee the queue is very short. http://www.bud.hu/english/passengers/faq/frequently-asked-questions-about-security-12939.html#ftl 1500 HUF / 5 EUR.

Comment: That's for security, not passport, control

Comment: True; but from my experience the normal security queue can be really bad.